# Invalidating a Java HTTP Session to redirect to a different server, without logging the user out

Tags: java, session, jboss, load-balancing

I am attempting the following flow:

1. Invalidate the HttpSession
2. Load balancer redirects the user to a server
3. User should already be logged in, irregardless of which server they are sent to.

Notes:

Sticky sessions are enabled, but should not matter when the session is invalidated. There are existing rules that log out a user after a certain amount of time, but I need to be able ensure that the user stays logged in when a certain method that invalidates the session is called.

The servers are not clustered and so no server is aware of the other server. It is also impossible to implement Redis or similar in the current environment.

The server is JBoss 7 (EAP 6.1)

I am stuck on the logical flow, and I can't seem to find someone that has done this alread, apart from invalidating with httpSession.invalidate()

Answer (score 0):

*but I need to be able ensure that the user stays logged in* - then why have those session timeout rules?  Which is more important: security or the user experience?

More secure approach and easiest to implement:  the front-end uses a timer to alert the user to inactivity a few minutes before the session expires.  If the user ignores the alert, too bad.  The user must log back in.

Less secure approach and harder to implement, but a better user experience: When the user logs in store a token in shared storage which is associated with the user.  Each request includes the token **as a header or posted value but never as query parameter** so if the session expires the token can be looked up to get the trusted user, and log the user back in **without a password**.  Of course, any session context will still be lost since the session had expired so depending on what the user was doing this could cause confusion for the user.

But how long should the token be considered valid?  Suppose the session timeout is 15 minutes (which is a regulatory requirement for some apps), how long should the token be trusted?  30 minutes, 1 hour, 24 hours?  It's a slippery slope.
Again, which is more important: security or the user experience?